# Tutorial for saving an array of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, xcode, nsmutablearray

Is there a tutorial for saving and restoring an array of custom objects?

Comment: 14 Questions in a 24 Hour period, 6 of those about this. Maybe this would of been the best question to ask first? :/

Comment: It's not my fault people can't answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you mean saving to disk and retrieving at some later point.

This is known as archiving in objective-c and can be performed on any object that implements NSCoding, including NSArray.

This looks like a fairly good tutorial [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php).

Comment: That tutorial is for cocoa not cocoa-touch. It also uses deprecated methods.

Answer (score -3):

Like [NSUserDefaults](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)???

Comment: I'm trying to save custom objects so it's a little more involved than just using NSUserDefaults.